# Finding a basis of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue -1 of the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find a basis of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue -1 of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}3&0&-12&-4\\4&-1&-11&-3\\2&0&-7&-2\\-2&0&7&2\end{bmatrix}$

**NOTE: POST HAS BEEN UPDATED SINCE DOWNVOTES**

So I did $A - -1I = A + I = \begin{bmatrix}4&0&-12&-4\\4&0&-11&-3\\2&0&-6&-2\\-2&0&7&3\end{bmatrix}$ then I got the RREF of:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&2\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I then got $x_1 = -2x_4$ and $x_3 = -x_4$ can someone tell me why $x_3 \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_4 \begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is not correct?? They are acting like I should have a $1$ on the $x_2$ spot in my first vector solution which makes no sense!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The eigenspace $E(A, -1)$ is defined as $\mathrm{Null}(A-(-1)I) = \mathrm{Null}(A+I)$

So add the identity matrix to $A$ and then solve for the null space of $A + I$.

**Added After Edits:**
One way to see that the first vector is not correct is to apply the linear transformation $A$ to it and observe that $A(v) \neq -v$. For example:

$$A\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} -12 \\ -11 \\ -7 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}$$

which doesn't look like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. So what you found is not an eigenvector

After I went through the process myself, I found that your row reduction was correct, so the problem is not there.

The last step is to set up the equations to solve for the null space of your matrix. You should have:

$$x_1 = -2x_4$$
$$x_3 = -x_4$$

Let's select 1 as $x_4$, and we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

exactly like you did.

However, notice that the two equations depend on only one value, but the null space is 2 dimensional (clearly, you have two rows of zeros), so there must be something else that the null space is dependent on. You actually have 2 free variables total. And we can see that fixing either $x_1, x_3$, or $x_4$ uniquely determines the other two variables.

What you seemed to forget is that $x_2$ is also a free variable. There are no restrictions at all on $x_2$ set by the equations, $x_2$ can be anything at all! So taking $x_2 = 1$, and picking $x_4 = 0$, we get that the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is also an eigenvector. You could easily verify this by applying the row reduced transformation to this vector. It is indeed in the null space. So the correct basis of the eigenspace is:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

If you notice, if you pick $x_3 = 1$, like you seemed to, then it determines that $x_4 = -1$ and $x_1 = 2$. The first vector you provided is not an eigenvector.

Comment: See my updated comments in the OP